# ¿Cómo fusionar las filas de un DataFrame cuyo índice tiene fechas y horas en un DataFrame con sólo fechas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

He creado una función para crear un DataFrame con los precios de las acciones cada día al cierre de los mercados a partir de una lista de teletipos. Quería una línea para cada día pero hay diferentes líneas para un día porque cada mercado cierra a una hora diferente. ¿Cómo podría fusionar líneas para el mismo día?

Se supone que no debe haber más de un precio por día por acción para cada día.

La funcion:

```
from yahooquery import Ticker
import pandas as pd

def price_maker(tickers):
    df_concated = pd.DataFrame()
    for ticker_name in tickers:
        ticker = Ticker(ticker_name)
        df = ticker.history(period='max', interval='1d')
        df_concated = pd.concat([df_concated, df['close'].rename(str(ticker_name))], axis=1)
    return df_concated

tickers = ['AF.PA','GOOG']
df = price_maker(tickers)
df
```

Los resultados:

```
                        AF.PA       GOOG
2000-01-03 08:00:00     19.690001   NaN
2000-01-04 08:00:00     20.580000   NaN
2000-01-05 08:00:00     20.500000   NaN
2000-01-06 08:00:00     21.000000   NaN
2000-01-07 08:00:00     20.889999   NaN
...     ...     ...
2020-04-29 07:00:00     4.590000    NaN
2020-04-29 13:30:00     NaN         1341.479980
2020-04-30 07:00:00     4.647000    NaN
2020-04-30 13:30:00     NaN         1348.660034
2020-05-01 20:00:02     NaN         1320.609985
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entendí a la pregunta, solo te interesa como tal hasta el día en la fecha y no te importa la hora de cierre. Por lo que yo haría lo siguiente:

```
from yahooquery import Ticker 
import pandas as pd

def price_maker(tickers):
    df_concated = pd.DataFrame()
    for ticker_name in tickers:
        ticker = Ticker(ticker_name)
        df = ticker.history(period='max', interval='1d')
        df_concated = pd.concat([df_concated, df['close'].rename(str(ticker_name))], axis=1)
        df_concated.index = pd.to_datetime(df_concated.index) # Trans a fecha.
        df_concated = df_concated.resample("1D").sum() # Reagrupamos por dia
    return df_concated

tickers = ['AF.PA','GOOG'] 
df = price_maker(tickers) 
df
```

Los resultados sería:

```
    AF.PA   GOOG
2000-01-03  19.690001   NaN
2000-01-04  20.580000   NaN
2000-01-05  20.500000   NaN
2000-01-06  21.000000   NaN
2000-01-07  20.889999   NaN
... ... ...
2020-04-27  4.500000    1275.880005
2020-04-28  4.440000    1233.670044
2020-04-29  4.590000    1341.479980
2020-04-30  4.647000    1348.660034
2020-05-01  NaN 1320.609985
```

Solo tienes que revisar que en efecto no exista más de una entrada por día, de lo contrario tienes que revisar los duplicados y determinar si tomar un promedio, o simplemente el más reciente. Espero te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias! ¿Sabes cómo deshacerte de los fines de semana? Esos son los días en que el mercado está cerrado. En mi marco de datos tiene una calificación de 0, así que hice `df = df[~df.isin([0])].dropna()`.  Pero este no es el mejor método, si una empresa desaparece, por ejemplo.

Comment: Hola! Ya que tienes la fecha en formato "datetime", puedes manipularlo más sencillo. Tiene funciones como:  `year, month, day, weekday `. En este caso utilizando `weekday`te regresa el día de la semana como 0 el lunes y 6 el domingo. Entonces quedaría, filtrando todos los días menores a 5 te quedarías con los días entre semana: `df = df.reset_index()
df = df[df["index"].apply(lambda x: 5>x.weekday())]` @RevolucionforMonica